# UML Activity Diagram : Signals with Pins

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

- i want to ask if there is a possibility to use signals whether is      receiving or sending signal with a pin ?
- which means how i can represent an Email sending through a sending
  signal ?

Answer (score 1):

Action Pins are used to send objects. Thus you can create an object flow to the "email object" while the control flow can connect to a send event which will control further action flows.

[image]

In this example `Action1` writes the email to a buffer. `Action3` actively waits for an email via its InputPin (and only if the control flow has reached it).

`Action1` continues to send an asynchronous signal via `EMail Notification. This signal is received by`Action4` and will start a concurrent flow.

Comment: i feel like it's redundant, but for the sending email shouldn't it be SendEmail rather than Email ?

Comment: That name would probably fit better (I was lazy typing the example...). It's sort of redundant (in this example). Without the signal `Action3` would start right with the receipt of the email. With the signal it only starts when this is triggered. This is just an example, you know...

Comment: @MohamedHmini, since you have the answer that worked for you, would you mind upvoting it (by clicking an arrow up) and marking the correct answer (by clicking a tick under the voting part)? That will indicate others a useful answer.

Comment: @Ister Thanks for making a reminder. Now looking at this old post it seems that it has flaws. `EMail` has two outgoing Control Flows but only one will get a token. I have to revisit send events. Probably a fork is needed here.  Also I'm now asking myself about an object flow and a control flow. What happens with the token the action currently holds? I need to dig into that once again....

Comment: @Ister It looks like instead of having a connector from EMail to Action3 there should be a receive event on the Action3 side instead. Anyway it seems pointless as the mail will be pulled from the pin anyway. I'll make an update...